# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid indexPath'

Tags: swift2

Swift 2 is doing my head in!

I have adapted :

```
func addConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions? = nil, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView]) {
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: options!, metrics: metrics, views: views))
}

func addUniversalConstraints(format format: String, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions, metrics: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, views: [String: UIView]) {
    addConstraints(format: "H:\(format)", options: options, metrics: metrics, views: views)
    addConstraints(format: "V:\(format)", options: options, metrics: metrics, views: views)
}
```

Though no I have an error in this line

```
public func selectRowAtIndex(index: Index) {
    selectedRowIndex = index

    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(
        NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0),
        animated: false,
    /**Error->*/    scrollPosition: .Middle)
}
```

Thanks again if you can help. :)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and examined the values are valid?

Comment: no solution, but it's a bad idea to declare the `NSLayoutFormatOptions` as optional with a default `nil` value and force unwrap the value later. Replace `options: NSLayoutFormatOptions? = nil` with `options: NSLayoutFormatOptions = NSLayoutFormatOptions()` if you really need a default value

Comment: I changed the scrollPosition: .Middle to scrollPosition: .None solved the problem as a work around